# How do I start a genymotion virtual device from a command prompt ( not using commands that can only run with Business license)

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I update my genymotion version from 2.6.0 to 2.7.2.

I used to start my virtual device using the
 open -a /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app --args --vm-name 'nexus_7' 'Google Nexus 7 - 5.0.0 - API 21 - 800x1280' command.

when I use this command now I get an error:

"Unable to start the virtual device.
The specified virtual device was not found in VirtualBox list."

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and updated to the newest version of Genymotion to test this out, and the following series of commands seems to work without any problems:

```
cd /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app/Contents/MacOS
./player --vm-name "Exact Name of Virtual Device"
```

***Obvious explanation of commands***: This is probably unnecessary, but just in case anybody does not understand what the commands are doing, here is a brief explanation: `cd /Applications/Genymotion.app...` is simply navigating within the app folder to a specific location. And `./player ...` is running the `player` executable within that folder.

As an example of what you should enter in after the `--vm-name` parameter, the following is what I executed in my test: *"Google Nexus 7 - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 800x1280"* Yours will likely be different, but that is the exact name of a device that I have set up in Genymotion.

I tested this with Genymotion v2.7.2 running on OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.3. Additionally, my Genymotion installation is only registered for Personal Use and it has never been registered for Business or Enterprise use, so I would expect that this command will work on your machine as well.